# How can I store many txt files in order to be embedded in the source code without being visible to the user?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, zimbra

I'm a blind person and I'm trying to create a win form app that aims to help people with visual impairments to learn better the keyboard. There are different levels in this program. such as: match characters, match words and match sentences. Almost I finished everything,   but I miss the technique of storing txt files in the source code in order to be invisible to the user in the program files.
Any suggestion?

Comment: What is the connection between this question and the Zimbra Collaboration Server software? Anyway, I think you want to look into resources/resource files or perhaps content assets.

Comment: You mean https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3314140/how-to-read-embedded-resource-text-file ?

Comment: Have you solved the problem?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the StreamWriter method.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.streamwriter?view=net-7.0

A complete example:

```
internal class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // Get the directories currently on the C drive.
        DirectoryInfo[] cDirs = new DirectoryInfo(@"c:\").GetDirectories();

        // Write each directory name to a file.
        using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter("Demo.txt"))
        {
            foreach (DirectoryInfo dir in cDirs)
            {
                sw.WriteLine(dir.Name);
            }
        }

        // Read and show each line from the file.
        string line = "";
        using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader("Demo.txt"))
        {
            while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(line);
            }
        }
    }
}
```